# Morphology: Machine-Learning

Tags: morphology, morphosyntax

Isn't the compound 'machine learning' problematic, inasmuch as the non-head of the compound is the external argument of learning. This would make it an auspicious compound (http://www.bobaljik.uconn.edu/papers/compounds.pdf). How are we to understand the compound?

Comment: That's not a problem if you call it statistical learning instead :P Joking aside, my lay speculation, based on how I understand the term, is that 'machine learning' isn't deverbalised from 'machines learn', but rather 'learning' as a noun is modified by 'machine' (like 'human behaviour', or 'animal morphology', or whatever). Probably I intuited this way because 'learning' is already fairly established as a noun (that's beneficial to your learning) and 'machine' already appears in a lot of compounds like this (machine language, machine gun). Do you think that works?

Comment: Noun compounds are always problematic. _Machine learning_ can mean learning **by** machine(s), **for** machine(s), **about** machine(s), or **with** machine(s), for instance, and those are not the only ones. Every time one loses words, one loses structure and therefore gains ambiguity.

Answer (score 4):

It's one of many kinds of compounds, and is not even exocentric (its head is "learning").

As it happens, it is exactly parallel to "machine stitching" (recorded in COHA in 1917) and "book learning" (in COHA from 1835).

Comment: That's the instrument interpretation. I would normally associate _machine learning_ with the agent interpretation; i.e, more like _hand-stitching_, where a personal agent is involved (_hand_ is just a metonym for _person_). I.e, it's the machine that's learning, not somebody else.

Comment: I never thought of that meaning ,@jlawler, but you're probably right: I now understand a part of the original question that I didn't understand at first. It also never occurred to me that 'hand' in _hand-stitching_ might be metonymic.